# Is there a way to change multiple file extensions at once on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-rename

If I have a bunch of files with one file extension, is there a way to quickly change them to another file extension without having to manually change one file at a time? The Microsoft support page gives a method for quickly renaming many files, but it only changes the names and keeps the original extensions, even if I have the option set to show file extensions when renaming a file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have a few utilities available.

**Powershell**

Use [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.4) in combination with [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.4)

```
Get-ChildItem "*.png" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "\.png$",".jpg" }
```

**Command prompt**

Use the [ren](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ren) command

```
ren *.png *.jpg
```

**Power Rename**

The [Power Rename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb430.png) utilty of [PowerToys](https://aka.ms/installpowertoys).

- Set the current extension, then the extension to change to.
- Apply to: `Extension only`
- Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>

[image]

**Note:** This assumes that you are on the folder where the files are located. If not, you need to `cd` to the correct locations for the first two examples.

Comment: +1 power rename is a great solution.

Comment: Shouldn't there be quotes around the `*` in the `ren` commandline?

Comment: @allo I just tested it, and the quotes are not necessary, even if the filename itself has spaces. I believe you would need the quotes in Linux, though.

Comment: @allo, in DOS, glob expansion is done by the program being run, unlike Linux, where glob expansion is done by the shell.

Comment: The pattern `".png"` for the PowerShell `-replace` is not quite correct. `-replace` expects a **Regular Expression** as pattern, where `.` stands for _any_ character, not the literal `.`, so it must be escaped to avoid unexpected results. And since only the extension is to be changed, the pattern should also be anchored to the end of the string: `{ $_.Name -replace "\.png$", ".jpg" }`. Doesn't matter too much with "png", but if someone reads this and, for example, tries to rename .gif to .jpg, then "My gifted child.gif" would become "My.jpgted child.jpg".

Comment: @user314159 I have changes based on your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the GUI program [ant renamer](https://antp.be/software/renamer) which has a portable version and can be run from a USB stick.